Connection Problem with MSSQL testcontainer
I try to get a test with testcontainers and MSSQL running, but the test gets stuck.
So, I created this little test below and the database is coming up. I get some warnings in the logs, while it is waiting for the database to startup, but I guess we can ignore these.
Flyway migrations get executed without any errors.
The test was successful at first, until I wanted to validate the data in the database without any spring magic.
This is where my test gets stuck. Also connecting to the database, while debugging isn't possible.
Has anyone an idea what I am doing wrong?

@Testcontainers
@DataJpaTest
@AutoConfigureTestDatabase(replace = AutoConfigureTestDatabase.Replace.NONE)
class IntegrationTest {


    @Container
    static MSSQLServerContainer<?> mssqlserver = new MSSQLServerContainer<>("mcr.microsoft.com/mssql/server:2019-latest")
            .acceptLicense()
            .waitingFor(Wait.forListeningPort()) 
            .waitingFor(Wait.forLogMessage(".*Started.*", 1));

    private static String jdbcUrl;
    private static String username;
    private static String password;

    @DynamicPropertySource
    static void neo4jProperties(DynamicPropertyRegistry registry) {
        jdbcUrl = mssqlserver.getJdbcUrl();
        username = mssqlserver.getUsername();
        password = mssqlserver.getPassword();

        registry.add("spring.datasource.url", () -> jdbcUrl);
        registry.add("spring.datasource.username", () -> username);
        registry.add("spring.datasource.password", () -> password);
        registry.add("spring.datasource.migrate", () -> "true");
    }

    @Autowired
    private TodoRepository todoRepository;

    private RestApi restApi;

    @Test
    void name() {
        restApi = new RestApi(todoRepository);
        restApi.addToList("Test todo");
        var todos = restApi.getList();
        assertTrue(todos.contains("Test todo"));

        String query = "SELECT id, task FROM todos";

        // Try-with-resources to ensure resources are closed properly
        try (Connection connection = DriverManager.getConnection(jdbcUrl, username, password);
             Statement statement = connection.createStatement();
             ResultSet resultSet = statement.executeQuery(query)) {

            // Process the result set
            while (resultSet.next()) {
                int id = resultSet.getInt("id");
                String task = resultSet.getString("task");
                System.out.println("ID: " + id + ", Task: " + task);
            }

        } catch (SQLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

Minimal working example can be found here:
https://github.com/FelixHerz/testcontainers-test

On which code row are you stuck? Pretty sure you should be able to connect to the container during debugging too!

It is stuck when opening a new connection DriverManager.getConnection

A Test with @JdbcTest is completing successful though.

Aside... there are multiple places in the container log where SQL Server reports something "started" while it is starting up, you might have more luck waiting for a unique message like "Recovery is complete."

Also, from your docker-compose.yml file, mounting over /var/opt/mssql is likely to break a lot of things (that reside in the .system subdirectory, for example). Much safer to mount on the specific directories that you need, such as /var/opt/mssql/data and /var/opt/mssql/log.

@AlwaysLearning, thanks for those recommendations. Do you have a proper best practices guide for mssql and docker? I'd be interested.

Just noticed that @JdbcTest and @SpringBootTest work in my demo app. On my big scale enterprise application, that is not what I want to do though.
